# How to set Node.js fibers blocking

Tags: javascript, node.js, fibers

I'm trying to create a more synchronized db module using node-mongodb-native. Currently stuck on fiberizing a db.open

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: I have just taken a look an node fibers but still haven't got a clue what it is.